# Why can't I find anyone who has discovered the (irrational) constant 1.29128...?

Tags: sequences-and-series, constants

The constant is exactly $\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{1}{n^n}$. Why does it seem that no one has written about it? Did I not search well enough? If so, what is the name for it? If not, it is not sufficiently "interesting?" I can't find it anywhere, which seems very strange.

(I apologize about how little my experience in higher maths I have...)

Comment: Are you so sure that it's irrational?

Comment: @Milo Brandt It seems a little weird for it to be rational, doesn't it?

Comment: See the [sophomore's dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: @MiloBrandt: yes it is. Due to Lagrange inversion theorem, such a constant is related with the Lambert function. If such a constant were rational, it would give $e^a=b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. That may happen only at $a=0$ since $e$ is a trascendental number.

Comment: The OEIS has a page about it: http://oeis.org/A073009. You can find it by typing in the digits 1, 2, 9, 1, 2, 8 into the search bar. Also see the references in the "Links" section on that page.

Comment: But obviously its "weirdness" is not enough to prove its irrationality.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up (this is another example of a Stack Exchange question that gets answered in the comments).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio is there a way to prove a number is  irrational with knowing its Surd form ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha: what is the *Surd form* of a number?

Comment: I don't think transcendentals have surd forms. (I also don't think "surd" is capitalized.) How would they?

Comment: @ritwiksinha : We can even prove certain numbers are transcendental (hence irrational) without knowing their surd form.  Infinite number of examples:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number

Comment: The constant is not interesting or useful enough to name.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how is this constant related to Lambert's function? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @arctictern "Interest" is in the eye of the beholder -- that's a bit hard to argue in that case, no?

Comment: Since I just discovered that I was *not* the first to discover that (it was unlikely anyway), it seems like it would be rare for *new* math to be discovered. Am I wrong?

Comment: @asherdrummond Erm... how do you do the logical jump between the first and second part of your sentence?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make that clear... this has happened multiple times, so it seems like most math within what most think of has already been discovered, and the few who this does not apply to are the ones who invent new math.

Comment: @EricTowers If the number is only irrational not transcendental then is there a way ?

Comment: @arctictern Now we have found out that is *does* have a name...

Comment: @ritwiksinha : Since nearly all irrationals are transcendental, you seem to be interested in very few irrationals.  The remaining irrationals are algebraic.  Consequently, the non-rational roots (if any) of a polynomial are nontranscendental irrationals.  Most of these do not have representations as surds (even in principle).  (For more on this, study solvability by radicals.)  So write down a random high degree polynomial that has no rational roots (via rational roots test), and you have (almost surely) nontranscendental irrationals without any surd representation.

Comment: I just discovered the constant $\sum_{n=1}^∞(\frac{1}{n^{n^n}})$. And I discovered $\sum_{n=1}^∞(\frac{1}{n^{n-1}})$. And $\sum_{n=1}^∞(\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{2}n}})$. Why can't I find anyone who has discovered those?

Comment: @immibis Obviously, this is very subjective, but I feel that this constant (the Sophomore's Dream) is more significant than those. I assume the Sophomore's Dream would also have more interesting properties.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Can you please provide some more details (say a link to some reference) on how rationality of this constant would lead to equation of form $e^{a} = b$ with $a, b$ being rational?

Comment: `this is another example of a Stack Exchange question that gets answered in the comments` -- it being essentially a [name that thing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How does this question have any similarities to the "name that thing" questions? It *is* naming something, but not guessing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you perhaps help out [at this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346259/is-sophomores-dream-transcendental)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What?  You mean the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)?  (Actually, the "dream" is that $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$, but this is just two representations of your value.)

Your value appears in [the ISC](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.291285997&lookup_type=simple), associated with that sum.

This sequence of digits appears in the OEIS as [A073009](https://oeis.org/A073009) (with various references, including to Bernoulli's proof that the integral equals the sum).

Comment: But what is the name of the constant?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I think the constant is also referred to as the Sophomore's Dream.

Comment: Why do you think it has "a name" other than "the constant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$"?  That's a short and unambiguous identifier.

Comment: That's not true online when whatever one is typing in only supports plain ASCII (or even Unicode) (especially since unrendered AsciiMath is very annoying to read). *Brief Tangent: Is there a better way to format two pairs of parentheses in a row?*

Comment: All I typed was plain ASCII.  In the comment, at the ISC, at the OEIS, et al...

Comment: You also used rendered MathJax.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Do you know anything about my browser?  Let me introduce you to [lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

Comment: But those were quite annoying to read. It's like reading X-SAMPA (try understanding some words in Taa and the like, it's impossible to read in SAMPA/X-SAMPA and so on).

Comment: I already know about lynx, but in Math Stack Exchange, ASCII text rendered in dollar signs is rendered as MathJax and, at least in my opinion, as I've said before, it takes a while and is annoying to read the ASCII version of MathJax (AsciiMath).

Comment: I've been reading it and writing it for a few years.  It's not quite automatic when running into someone else's spacing patterns, but I read mine pretty much fluently.  Also, there is no hope of MathJax rendering in a non-graphical or non-Javascript browser (or browser that has had those turned off).

Comment: @asherdrummond its standard math markup used by TeX, LaTeX, etc, and fairly ubiquitous in the math and science communities.

Comment: That's true, but it isn't truly universal, as it could be... if only someone (I might get to it) could create a more readable ASCII-based markup... *Another Brief Tangent: Is this an overuse of the ellipsis?*

Comment: @EricTowers: I'm surprised lynx can run all the javascript used by Math SE. If I disable it I can log in but can't view or post comments.

Comment: The asker specifically requested the /name/ of the constant.

Comment: If I were to make up a name, I'd use ​ Sophomore's constant . ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @asherdrummond Wow intending to improve on Knuth's (and a couple thousand volunteers work) is certainly a stretch goal.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : The OP asked many things, including its nonexistent name.

Comment: @DRF but not neccessarily impossible.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Certainly not impossible, but probably roughly as likely as getting a nobel prize in some discipline. I.e. Saying "I might get to it" in an offhand sort of way as though it's roughly as hard for you as mowing the lawn, is either very stupid or very arrogant IMO.

Comment: I would not go that far in saying it. It's a formatting language. Sure, the code would be hard to implement but I don't see how one couldn't reinvent in a way that looks nicer or improve on it. I can easily think of many flaws within mathjax. For instance, / should auto format as a fraction. After all, that is it's generally accepted format in higher mathematics.