# Is Sophomore's Dream Transcendental?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, transcendental-numbers

[Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) is the pair of identities
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-x}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}\\[20pt]
\int_0^1x^x\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n^{-n}
$$
Are these numbers transcendental?

Comment: Is there a simple way to compare $(n+1)^{n+1}$ and $\text{lcm}(1^1,2^2,\ldots,n^n)$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Are you trying to somehow relate the identities to $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question is rather open (cf. [this article](https://www.mathinterest.net/Math/Function/)). In general, proving a specific number irrational (or especially transcendental) is a very difficult thing to do (depending on the number in question, of course).

Comment: My initial plan was to understand if the partial sums of $C=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}$ provide convergents for $C$, but that is not the case, clearly. On the other hand the study of the integrals $$ \int_{0}^{1}x^m(1-x)^m x^{-x}\,dx$$ might lead to interesting consequences (here I am thinking to Beukers' proof of $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $e\not\in\mathbb{Q}$).